# How to supress tesseract TIFFReadDirectory Warnings under Windows?

Tags: tesseract, tiff, suppress-warnings, libtiff.net

I am using a Windows Distribution of Tesseract and have the problem that when each picture is converted from TIFF to text I get an (oldstyle!) Windows pop-up message with

"Unknown field with tag (number of tag) encountered", e.g.
"Unknown field with tag 292 encountered",
"Unknown field with tag 33300 encountered"

This prevents me from evaluating many TIFF pictures at once, since the pop-up stops the execution of the loop.

Anyone have an idea on how to supress the warning messages?